# knitr - unexpected '[['

Tags: r, knitr

I am getting the following error from `knitr`:

```
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src) : <text>:39:48: unexpected '[['
38:   ## make data.frame for "Generic" line
39:   vline.data <- data.frame(z = c(all_rep_coeff$[[
```

The error appears to come from using double brackets `[[` which is necessary to access a column by variable in a data.frame in R.

Is there a way around this error? Or another way to access a column in a data.frame by variable?

Comment: Are you using `$[[` or just `[[`? Can you share the snippet in your source file that this error is referring to?

Comment: If the name of that column really starts with `[[` (which is bad), then you need to quote it: `all_rep_coeff$'[[name with brackets'`. If it doesn't, then you are using the wrong syntax, see http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html

Comment: Thanks @AnandaMahto, removing the $ solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have incorrectly referred to your column name. There is no need to use both `$` and `[[`.

Removing the `$` should solve this problem.